# android N load library

Tags: android, loadlibrary

The fail log like these:

```
library "/data/user/0/xxx/lib/libCpt.so" 
("/mnt/asec/xxx/lib/arm/libCpt.so")needed or dlopened by 
"/system/lib/libnativeloader.so" is not accessible for 
the namespace: [name="classloader-namespace", ld_library_paths="", 

default_library_paths="", permitted_paths="/data:/mnt/expand"]
```

default_library_paths is empty, is right?

The case is happened when update android m to android n, and app run failed.

Someone can help me ?